# Regex within XML

Tags: regex, xml, adobe

I am trying to load a regex pattern matching code into Adobe DC Pro to match patterns equal to phone numbers, excluding a unique one, which we will say ends in '0123'.

So doing some research, using ".*(?<!0123)" I am able to come up with the following:

```
(\b\s?)((\+?\d{1}(-|\s|\.|_)?)((\(\d{3}\)|\d{3})(-|\s|\.|_)?)|((\(\d{3}\)|\d{3})(-|\s |\.|_)?))?(\d{3}(-|\s|\.|_)?\d{4}).*(?<!0123)(\b)
```

But the problem is that Adobe DC Pro takes in XML and the regex code I have to use for negative lookbehind includes the '<' character which is special.

So I try using '&lt!;' special character instead of '<' and get

```
(\b\s?)((\+?\d{1}(-|\s|\.|_)?)((\(\d{3}\)|\d{3})(-|\s|\.|_)?)|((\(\d{3}\)|\d{3})(-|\s |\.|_)?))?(\d{3}(-|\s|\.|_)?\d{4}).*(?&lt;!0123)(\b)
```

In this case, at least adobe DC pro detects that as a proper pattern, but its does not yield the results that I seek (and I have semi confirmed to work using online RegEx testers)

So to sum it all up:

- Am I using the escape character correctly?
- Is there an alternate way of constructing my regex query to just not use XML Special Characters?
- Any other ideas

Thank you in advance.

Comment: `>` is `&gt;` and `<` is `&lt;`, `(?&lt;!0123)` is `(?<!0123)`, a lookbehind, but are you sure the regex flavor supports lookbehinds?

Comment: I suppose that is a possibility, but trying to determine that from adobe is like getting blood from a stone.  Is there another way to achieve what I am doing without a look behind?

Comment: Yes, I think there is. Please check https://regex101.com/r/wsOYZ9/2

Comment: Please check https://regex101.com/r/wsOYZ9/2 and if anything does not match as expected, please let know.

Comment: Yes that worked Than kyou

Answer (score 0):

The lookbehind is unnecessary, you need to use a `(?!0123\b)` lookahead beore the last `\d{4}`.

However, the whole regex should be pruned as it contains too many redundant parts. Besides, the `\b` that is used before `\+` will fail all cases when `+` is not appearing right after a word char.

You need

```
 (?:(?:\+?\b\d[-\s._]?)?(?:\(\d{3}\)|\b\d{3})[-\s._]?)?\d{3}[-\s._]?(?!0123\b)\d{4}\b
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/wsOYZ9/3)

**Details**

- `(?:(?:\+?\b\d[-\s._]?)?(?:\(\d{3}\)|\b\d{3})[-\s._]?)?` - an optional sequence of:

  - `(?:\+?\b\d[-\s._]?)?` - an optional `+`, word boundary, digit and an optional `-`, whitespace, `.` or `_`
  - `(?:\(\d{3}\)|\b\d{3})` - either `(`, 3 digits, `)` or a word boundary and 3 digits
  - `[-\s._]?` - an optional `-`, whitespace, `.` or `_`
- `\d{3}` - 3 digits
- `[-\s._]?` - an optional `-`, whitespace, `.` or `_`
- `(?!0123\b)\d{4}` - 4 digits that are not equal to `01234`
- `\b` - word boundary.

Comment: Thank you for this.  Now to try and figure out how to exclude starting characters or strings (Like - or $)

Comment: @user1399783 Remove them, `.replace(/[$+-]/g, '')`